# Mocking ResourceLoading with JMockit

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmockit

My application uses a Singleton that holds the config settings. This is the Code:

```
private PropertiesSingleton() throws Exception {
    InputStream appstream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
    props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(appstream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(Log.FATAL,
                "Cannot find application.properties in classpath.", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Normaly my application runs inside a container. For my unittest I have to make the application.properties available to be loaded. I tried it like this:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception {


    final FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("../path/to/config/application.properties");
    new NonStrictExpectations(ClassLoader.class) {
        {
            String.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"); result = inStream;
        }
    };
}
```

The test will not start but print this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.VerifyError
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
at de.lpm.ejb.archiving.ArchiveHandlerBeanTest$2.<init>(ArchiveHandlerBeanTest.java:50)
at de.lpm.ejb.archiving.ArchiveHandlerBeanTest.init(ArchiveHandlerBeanTest.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is simply not possible to mock the ClassLoader, because it is there first. You can not do stuff before the class loader comes to existence. So try to mock the caller, not the class loader.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I figured I can still chime in. All you need to do is extract this into your own Loader class:

```
InputStream appstream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
```

Similar to this:

```
public class MyResourceLoader {
    public InputStream getResource(String location){
        this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream();
    }
}
```

Then you simple need to use the new "MyResourceLoader" and then mark it as @Mocked in your test. I hope this helps.